# Фото и подпись в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как сделать так что-бы бот смог отправить фото с подписью пользователю

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baiogram%5D+caption)

Comment: Я ничего не дублировал

Comment: @шарифмирзаев "дубликат" означает, что похожи вопрос (вопросы) уже задавался ранее, и вероятно там уже есть ответы на ваш вопрос.